# Allow user to export .SVG file in python

Tags: javascript, python, svg, plotly

I'm implementing some python functions to analyse and plot figures using python, and these outputs will be implemented in interactive way in web app.

However, I'd like that user could be able to export charts as .svg file. Something like the function "plot as png" from plotly library, but with .SVG file.

Do you, guys, know how to run this kind of code? Any way would help a lot!

Thank you

Comment: Use 'fig.write_image("fig1.svg")' inside your function

Comment: Dear Hamzah, I've already tried this approach.
But when I use  'fig.write_image("fig1.svg")', the file are saved in server machine. I would like to "take a picture" of the interactive plot and save it as .svg in the user machine!

Answer (score 0):

The `write_image` method will write to an in-memory stream instead of a file; you can then read the svg text from the stream and send it to the user through your web app:

```
import io
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16])

with io.BytesIO() as output:
    fig.write_image(output, format='svg')
    svg = output.getvalue().decode("utf-8")

print(svg)
```